# Time series plots, polynomial coefficients and PCA

Tags: time-series, pca, polynomial

I have several time series plots that I have their polynomial coefficients (curve fitting using Matlab polyfit). Is it possible and valid to use Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to try to classify them? Is it mandatory that all the plots will have the same coefficient numbers (degree of polynomial fit)? limitation to consider? Any other alternatives?

Comment: Could you explain how you are thinking of using the curve coefficients in a PCA of the time series?  How would these be related?

Comment: Using the curve coefficients as the variables for the principal component analysis.

Comment: How would you apply PCA when Matlab fits polynomials of varying degrees?  Although you could (artificially) set all higher coefficients to zero, that has obvious problems, so what did you have in mind?

Comment: This is my question, how to do it and is it valid.